# Increase font size of ListItem in Combo box that comes as suggested in dropdown

Tags: c#, visual-studio, combobox, dropdown

I am using Combo box while creating Desktop Application using C# in Visual Studio, I increased the font size to "20" now when I run the application and click the dropdown button list elements font-size also increased.
[image]

That's fine. But, when I write something in the combo box it gives suggestions as shown in the picture below.
[image]

I, also want to increase the font size of this suggestion list, I have set  "AutoCompleteMode" property set to "suggest". Is anybody can help me with this?

Answer (score 1):

The font of the auto-complete text presented is fixed. There is no corresponding properties to set it.

A workaround is that you can create a custom control and replace the  suggest-drop-down with custom listbox.

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    comboBox1.Size = new Size(120, 30);
    listBox.SelectedIndexChanged += ListBox_SelectedIndexChanged;
}

private void ListBox_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    comboBox1.Text = listBox.Text;
    listBox.Visible = false;
}

ListBox listBox = new ListBox();

// event triggered when the user enters text
private void comboBox1_TextUpdate(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // set the font of listbox to be consistent with combobox
    listBox.Font = comboBox1.Font;
    // add listbox below combobox
    listBox.Location = new Point(comboBox1.Location.X, comboBox1.Location.Y + comboBox1.Height);

    // filter suggest items
    listBox.Items.Clear();
    foreach (string item in comboBox1.Items)
    {
        if (item.StartsWith(comboBox1.Text) && comboBox1.Text != string.Empty)
        {
            listBox.Items.Add(item);
        }
    }

    listBox.Visible = listBox.Items.Count > 0;
    this.Controls.Add(listBox);
}
```

Test result：

[image]

Comment: @PUBG GAMING Does this help you? If so, please [`vote on / accept it`](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 0):

Those are actually two areas which you can configure independently. According to this MSDN article,

To change settings:

1. Go to Tools – Options – Environment - Fonts and Colors
2. Under Show settings for: select either Statement Completion or Editor Tooltips (for Parameter Info and Quick Tips)
3. Change either the font or font size