# How to set height of a list box to match the number of elements in it using C#?

Tags: c#, winforms, listbox, autosize

I am creating desktop application using C# and I want to set height of list Box with respect to number of elements in it. For example in picture below,

[image]

I have four elements in list it should show all the four at once but it is showing only two. I want to change height randomly on the base of number of elements in it. Any one can help me with this?

Comment: it is a simple text box I use it with list box

Comment: yes it is WinForm

Comment: Olivier Rogier‘s answer is right. If you are using the [code I provided earlier](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65227668/8335151). You can use the following code to set the ItemHeight of the listbox in constructor. `listBox.ItemHeight = comboBox1.ItemHeight;`

Answer (score 3):

You can write:

```
listBox1.Height = listBox1.ItemHeight * (listBox1.Items.Count + 1);
```

Also you can set a maximum limit to protect the form:

```
int count = listBox1.Items.Count + 1;
if ( count > 20 ) count = 20;
listBox1.Height = listBox1.ItemHeight * count;
```

Also you can use a maximum height or any other check instead of items count:

```
int height = listBox1.ItemHeight * count;
if ( height > 300 ) height = 300; 
listBox1.Height = height;
```

The `ItemHeight` depends on the font size.